# What are TestExecutionListeners, and what do they do?

Tags: spring, spring-test, spring-test-dbunit

As far as I understand, TestExecutionListeners act like `@BeforeClass` methods in JUnit. What I don't understand is why I need to use `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener`, `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` and `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener` to use `DbUnitTestExecutionListener`.

Normally without DbUnit, I can create and populate the database. Why suddenly do I need to use these listeners to do some `CRUD` for my database?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`TestExecutionListeners` provide various types of functionality to tests running in the Spring TestContext Framework.

If you are interested in what a particular listener does, the best way to find out is to read the Javadoc for the respective class. In addition, the [*Testing* chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing.html) of the Spring reference manual goes into detail about how to use each of the listeners and what they do.

In your particular case, if you're not using `@DirtiesContext`, then you don't need to use the `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener`. As for `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener` and `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`, you will likely need them to inject dependencies into your test (e.g., via `@Autowired`, `@Inject`, `@Resource`, etc.) and for transactional tests (i.e., tests annotated with `@Transactional`).

Note as well that the aforementioned listeners are enabled by default. So if you've been using the Spring TestContext Framework *without* any custom listeners like the one for DbUnit, then you just never realized that the listeners existed. The section on [TestExecutionListener configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/testcontext-framework/tel-config.html) in the reference manual should also help clarify things. Note, however, that some features like merging and auto-detection of default listeners are only available in Spring Framework 4.1+.

Regards,

Sam *(author of the Spring TestContext Framework)*

Comment: Thanks Sam. I updated the links, since particularly the first link seemed to be an (imprecise) redirect now.